# Typeahead is not working when user types very fast

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using typeahead where on typing its showing suggestions in a search box, while suggestions are getting from the server.

Its working fine except when user types really fast.  For example if we type **storm** it's showing records. When type same word with speed, it's not showing its suggestions while I am getting data in **response**. I have checked by printing **JSON** just above the box so when I write storm fastly its showing **JSON** but not showing below suggestions.

Here is the html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="header.search"
    typeahead-on-select="searchClicked($item)"
    uib-typeahead="state as state.data.name for state in suggestions | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
    typeahead-min-length="0" placeholder="Søg..." search-products>
```

**search-products** is the directive use to broadcast search values. Here is the directive code.

```
APP.directive('searchProducts', searchProducts);
function searchProducts($state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(searchVal) {
                scope.$broadcast('searchTheProducts', searchVal);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the service call where we are getting data.

```
$scope.$on('searchTheProducts', function(event, query) {
    if (query) {
        headerService.getSearchSuggestions(query).then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.suggestions = response;
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

here is the service logic

```
  function getSearchSuggestions(query) {
    pendingRequests.cancelAll();
    var url = ApiBaseUrl + "/search/suggestions?query=" + query;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    pendingRequests.add({
        url: url,
        canceller: deferred
    });

    pending = true;
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        timeout: deferred.promise
    }).then(
        function(successData) {

            deferred.resolve(successData.data.data);
        },
        function(err) {

            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Could you add `<pre>{{header.search}} | {{suggestions|json}}</pre>` to your page and show us what it outputs when you type quickly?

Comment: ston | [
  {
    "type": "product",
    "data": {
 
     
      "name": "Stone Age piano"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "department",
    "data": {
      
    
      "name": "Stone Age Diet Food"
      
    }
  }
]

Comment: I wrote ston its showing output but in dropownlist showing nothing, when I pressed backspace suddenly its showing

Comment: Can you add the part of the code (_in the backend_) that returns the data to your `headerService` service. Meanwhile, what does your browser console show when `uib-typeahead` performs `HTTP` requests as you type?

Comment: you need to debounce the input, similar to `typeahead-wait-ms="400"`, try to do it on your api call, use the debounce rather than throttle

Comment: @entre nops :( I have tried

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri nothing show in console

Comment: @naCheex, can you add the logic for how you are returning the data from the server into your original post?

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri Please have a look now I have updated.

Comment: can we suggest slightly different approach ? without using custom directive to find if input is changed and fetch results according to it although the design pattern will remain same ?

Comment: @Angular_10 I have tried by removing custom directive and using ngkeypress ,but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom directive to fire the `$http` call to fetch the results whenever your input value changes.Instead you can do as below

```
<input type="text" ng-model="header.search"
    typeahead-on-select="searchClicked($item)"
    uib-typeahead="state as state.data.name for state in suggestions($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
    typeahead-min-length="0" placeholder="Søg..." >
```

In your JS controller you can write the function `$scope.suggestions()` to fetch the new results on query type.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.factory('dataProviderService', ['$http', function($http) {
        var factory = {};
        factory.getCities = function(input) {
            //I've used google api to fetch cities ..we can place our service call here..
          return  $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                params: {
                    address: input,
                    sensor: false
                }
            }).then(function(response) {//on success the results can be further processed as required..
                return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                    return item.formatted_address;
                });
            });

        };

        return factory;
    }]);

     app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', '$log','$http', 'dataProviderService', function($scope, $log,$http, dataProviderService) {
            $scope.suggestions= function(viewValue) {
                //you can call your own service call via a factory 
             return   dataProviderService.getCities(viewValue);

            };

        }]);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4Z027v3meFwbfRPlFzDV?p=preview) of the working sample for the above mentioned way,hope this helps you.In this approach no mater how fast you type you will always fetch fresh results instantly.

Comment: How suggestion will be populate on specific query?

Comment: when ever you type it will fetch results from  $scope.suggestions automatically, so if your service call is good enough to handle any type of input and give back results you will always get results in type ahead. Check the plunker and try out by typing anything.

Comment: @naCheex glad it helped you !

Comment: @ngCoder Thank you so much for this answer mate!! You have saved my day (night at the time of writing)!!! My requests were taking 300-900 ms but now it's taking less than 200 ms every time!! 
And thank you so much for asking the question OP!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you have:

```
angular.forEach(response, function(val, key) {
  $scope.suggestions= response;
});
```

If `response` is 100 items, then for some reason you're updating `$scope.suggestions` each time and this *may* be causing the problem. Simply remove the `angular.forEach` and just have `$scope.suggestions = response` instead.

Comment: Yes I have tried without foreach but its still behaving same. On first time when I write 3,4 chracters fastly its shows nothing and when I type it in normal speed its working fine.

Comment: And a request is made to your service?

Comment: ya and its getting response, I have checked by showing it just above the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `typeahead-wait-ms` attribute, so that you are not querying on every ketstroke:

```
<input typeahead-wait-ms="50">
```